# Django: Show View after password entry

Tags: django

How can I return a View only after letting the user enter a password which is checked against the link?

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    url = models.CharField(max_length=10) #a randomly created ASCII-string
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=10)

url_patterns = [path('foo/<url>/admin', views.foo, name='foo_admin'),]
```

So a user goes to url:

```
localhost/foo/bar
```

now he should enter the correct password to see the content of **model Foo** with **url='bar'**.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using class based views you will want the UserPassesTestMixin.

If you are using function based views you will want the user_passes_test decorator.

Both are described [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/default/). Both will essentially divert to the process flow to anything you define. In your case you will want to divert to whatever your using for password checking.

In case you haven't implemented a password scheme you can also read about the default django authentication at the same link.